# Connect google cloud to google colab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying since one week to connect my google colab notebook with google cloud, but doing the following steps in google cloud terminal:

```
1) gcloud init and then choose the appropriate settings
```

```
2) gcloud compute ssh --zone us-central1-a 'name' -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
```

```
3) one of these lines
jupyter notebook  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'  --port=8888  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 --no-browser, or 
jupyter notebook  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'  --port=8888  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

The output looks like this
[image]

So then I copy-paste the url into local runtime in google colab and the error is something like this
[image]

I followed these steps again, but I still have the same problem. Do you have any idea how to overcome this issue? I think it's problem which based on my computer.

Note that I turn off addblocker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replicating the setup and I am able to connect Google Colab to Google Cloud.

- After connecting to the server using,

  ```
  gcloud compute ssh --zone us-central1-a 'instance-name' -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
  ```
- Install and set up the necessary libraries to connect to a Colab frontend by using the following command:

  ```
  pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
  jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
  jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'  --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0  --no-browser
  ```
- To connect to a Colab frontend,  we get an URL as an output of the above command.
- When you click the URL’s in the terminal it will redirect to the Jupyter home page successfully without any problems.

Refer  [Colab+GCP Compute — how to link them together](https://medium.com/@senthilnathangautham/colab-gcp-compute-how-to-link-them-together-98747e8d940e) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much I figured out before some days. I have one more question, for some reason my linux rever contains python 3.7 but is using python 2.7. Do you know ho to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had a very silly basic mistake. First of all your server should be linux and then write the following code in the windows command:

`cloud compute ssh colab-backend --zone=europe-west4-a -L 8080:locahost:8081`, change it into the zone of your project and port

`type jupyter notebook  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'  --port=8888  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 --no-browser`

copy past the link into 'local runtime' in your google colab.